# Connect to Azure SQL DB from a Azure Functions in JS

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I am trying to connect to my Azure SQL DB from an azure function written in nodeJS. I have set the connection strings in the application settings and it still does not work. I used ODBC key for connection settings. Did anyone try this? Below is the sample code for my function

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

// Create connection to database
const config = process.env["sqldb_connection"];
var connection = new Connection(config);

// Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through
connection.on('connect', function(err)
   {
     if (err)
       {
          console.log(err)
       }
    else
       {
           queryDatabase()
       }
   }
 );

function queryDatabase()
   { console.log('Reading rows from the Table...');

       // Read all rows from table
     request = new Request(
          "SELECT ORG_ID,ORG_NAME FROM org",
             function(err, rowCount, rows)
                {
                    console.log(rowCount + ' row(s) returned');
                    process.exit();
                }
            );

     request.on('row', function(columns) {
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
            console.log("%s\t%s", column.metadata.colName, column.value);
         });
             });
     connection.execSql(request);
   }
```

I am getting an error saying

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerJS2. mscorlib: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

Comment: Try doing the connection as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo That does not work with Azure functions, you have to set the connection settings string in Application settings of the function

Comment: Did you add:
"package.json
 {
    "dependencies": {
        "tedious": "*"
    }
}"

as defined here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/682

Comment: Yes i added the packages and did a npm install from Kudu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Run the `npm install tedious` command in the **Kudu remote execution console** under `D:\home\site\wwwroot`.
2. In Azure Functions, all of your code should be put inside the `module.exports` function.
3. You should use `context.log()` instead of `console.log()`.
4. You really don't have to set the connection settings string in **Application settings** of the function.
5. You should inform the runtime when your code has finished by calling `context.done()`.

The following code works for me:

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    var config = {
        userName: '<userName>',
        password: '<password>',
        server: '<AzureSQLDBName>.database.windows.net',

        // If you're on Windows Azure, you will need this:
    options:
        {
                database: 'your DB',
                  encrypt: true
        }
};

    var connection = new Connection(config);

    connection.on('connect', function(err) {

        if (err) {
            context.log(err);

            context.res = {
                status: 500,
                body: "Unable to establish a connection."
            };
            context.done();

        } else {
            executeStatement();
        }
    });

    function executeStatement() {

        request = new Request("select 42, 'hello world'", function(err, rowCount) {
            if (err) {
                context.log(err);

                context.res = {
                    status: 500,
                    body: "Failed to connect to execute statement."
                };
                context.done();

            } else {
                context.log(rowCount + ' rows');
            }
        });

        request.on('row', function(columns) {
            columns.forEach(function(column) {
                context.log(column.value);
            });

            context.done();
        });

        connection.execSql(request);
    }
};
```

For more information, see [Azure Functions JavaScript developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs, yes I did the changes as you suggested and it works. But when I change the SQL query to read a table from my DB it does not work. 
For example, i have a table called fruits and a query as follows 
 `var sqlQuery = "SELECT apples,oranges FROM fruits;

  request = new Request(sqlQuery, function(err, rowCount, rows) {

   .... 

}`
When i do this i get a error saying 
`RequestError: Invalid object name 'fruits'`

Comment: @Ross - Did you ever resolve the problem> Sounds like you didn't have the database name in the connection string.