# Store data into SQL database from Azure IoTHub using Azure Functions without Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub

I have only one device connecting to Iothub and telemetry data is under 1k. In such situation, Azure Stream Analytics is too expensive.

Unlike Cosmos DB , Azure Functions has bindings of it , but SQL DB.

How can I store data from Azure Iothub into Azure SQL Database using azure function?

ps. I'm using Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely right, Stream Analytics would be overkill in this situation. My understanding of your questions is to use a Function to listen to device messages and store them in a SQL database. The steps you need to take are as follows:

1. Create an Azure Function with a Event Hub binding to the default endpoint of IoT Hub ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot-trigger?tabs=javascript))
2. Add the SQL connection string to the application settings of the Function ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings))
3. Write JavaScript to run SQL to the database (you might need to install dependencies as the answer states. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773289/connect-to-azure-sql-db-from-a-azure-functions-in-js))

Comment: Stuck on #2 . I'm not using VS and C#.. 
I wonder that is it available to use iotHub trigger with tedious(nodejs module) in index.js and insert data into SQL databaase ?

Comment: I changed the link for #2 to the documentation on how to add the application setting through the Azure portal instead, hope that helps. I also added a link to an SA question that shows how sample code and how to install the dependencies correctly.

Comment: After hours of testing , I finally stored telemetry data into my sql database. I also read [Working with JSON data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/json-features#working-with-json-data) which I could store JSON data in a table directly. Thank You Matthijs.