# Is there a way to ingest data from an Azure IoT hub to a MySQL database?

Tags: azure

I am trying to get data from my Azure IoT hub to a database, which will be then displayed on a website.

I have seen many ways to ingest data such as azure data explorer cluster and stream analytics jobs. However, the issue i have with data explorer is that i cannot get connection details for the database so i cot connect to it using code. As for stream analytics jobs, MySQL databases are not supported, and I have only have experience with MySQL.

Does anyone know a way i can ingest data from my Azure IoT hub to a MySQL database? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this solution answer to your question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380967/store-data-into-sql-database-from-azure-iothub-using-azure-functions-without-str

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write some code to do this.
You can for instance create an Azure Function that uses an `IoTHubTrigger` or `EventHubTrigger` so that the Function receives the messages that are available on the IoT Hub.  In the Function, you write code to make sure that the data is inserted in the appropriate tables in your database.

Find some documentation regarding this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp).